# Deleting image from a shape without deleting the shape itself

Tags: excel, vba

I used a code to insert a macro function that allows the user to insert an image in a shape using VBA.

How do I create a clear function for this in order to clear the image but leave the shape as it is?

The code that I used to insert the image is as follows:

```
`Sub insertPicture()
Dim FC As FileDialog
Set FD = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
With FD
.Title = "Select the picture to insert"
.InitialView = msoFileDialogViewLargeIcons
.InitialFileName = strFolder
.Filters.Clear
.Filters.Add "images", "*.gif; *.jpg; *.jpeg; *.png"
.FilterIndex = 2
.AllowMultiSelect = False
    If .Show = -1 Then
    ActiveSheet.Shapes("Rectangle 1").Fill.UserPicture .SelectedItems(1)
    Else
    MsgBox "No selection"
    Exit Sub
    End If
    End With
End Sub`
```

Comment: Probably just applying a different fill, such as a solid fill?

Comment: how do I make this a functional VBA code?

Comment: I'd recommend using the Macro Recorder while applying the fill you want and inspecting the resulting code.

Comment: That helped. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub clearImage()
    On Error Resume Next
    ActiveSheet.Shapes("Rectangle 1").Fill.UserPicture
    On Error GoTo 0
End Sub
```

Comment: The [UserPicture](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.fillformat.userpicture) method has a required argument 'PictureFile' for which the docs say "The file path to the picture file, or the name of the picture file if a link to the picture file currently exists". Your code omits this argument meaning a runtime error occurs, which is hidden by the use of `On Error Resume Next`.

Comment: Although this code might answer the question, I recommend that you also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.